# When exactly do we use let rec?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I know that `let rec` is used when I want `recursive`.

For example,

`let rec power i x = if i = 0 then 1.0 else x *. (power (i-1) x);;`

Ok, I understand that.

---

But how about this one:

`let x y = y + y in x 2`?

**Should I use `rec` inside?**

I think I should, because it has `x 2` inside, loading itself, but it seems it is fine with compiler.

**So when I should use `let rec` and shouldn't?**

---

Also, what is the difference between

`let (-) x y = y - x in 1-2-3;;`

and

`let rec (-) x y = y - x in 1-2-3;;`

**Are they both legal?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to understand the scoping rules of OCaml first.

When you write `let f XXX = YYY in ZZZ`, if you use `f` in `YYY` then you need `rec`. In both cases (ie with or without `rec`),`f` will be defined in `ZZZ`.

So:

```
let x y = y + y in
x 2
```

is perfectly valid.

For you second question: no it is not equivalent, if you try it on the toplevel, the second statement loop for ever and is equivalent to `let rec loop x y = loop y x in ()`. To understand why it is looping for ever, you can understand the application of `loop` as an expansion where the identifier is replaced by its body. so:

So `loop` body is `function x y -> loop y x`, which can be expanded to
`function x y -> (function a b -> loop b a) y x` (I've renamed the parameter names to avoid ambiguity), which is equivalent to `function x y -> loop x y` when you apply the body and so on and so on. So this function never does anything, it just loops forever by trying to expand/apply its body and swapping its arguments.

Comment: Could you please explain why `let rec (-) x y = y - x in 1-2-3;;` will loop forever?

Comment: @JacksonTale: You are defining the function `-` and then using it inside the function body `x-y`. So, `x-y` gets expanded (sort of) into `x-y` again...and again...

Comment: @AsiriRathnayake you mean I **rec** define **(-)**, then **y-x** will become **x-y** then **y-x** then **x-y**.....without stopping?

Comment: @JacksonTale: Yes, sorry, I didn't notice that the arguments get swapped. You are correct.

Comment: I've added some notes about the loop forever thing.

Comment: "if you use f in YYY then you need rec" Well, you could use `f` in `YYY` and not use `rec`, but then the `f` in `YYY` will be a different variable from the `f` you're defining